# Django Invalid block tag: endelse and ifequal

Tags: python, django

I want to use django `ifequal` and `else` tag to judge if a variable equals `80` or `22`. So, this is code:

```
{% if firewalls %}
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>IP address</th>
    <th>Function</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
{% endif %}
<tbody>
{% for firewall in firewalls %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ host_ip }} : {{ firewall.from_port }}</td>

    {% ifequal firewall.to_port 22 %} <td>Ssh Service</td>
    {% ifequal firewall.to_port 80 %} <td>Web Service</td>
    {% else %} <td>Unknown Service</td>{% endifequal %}{% endelse %}

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And the error is `Invalid block tag: 'endelse', expected 'else' or 'endifequal'`. Could someone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to the ifequal tag is to use the if tag and the == operator.Bow to power of '==' operator :

```
{% if firewall.to_port == 20 %}
   <td>Ssh Service</td>
{% elif firewall.to_port == 80 %}
   <td>Web Service</td>
{% else %}
   <td>Unknown Service</td>
{% endif %}
```

This way you are also saving your code processing time as it does not evaluate all if condition for every port number.

Comment: yes, in django 4.1 `Invalid block tag on line 38: 'ifequal', expected 'endblock'. ` change ifequal to if fixed

Answer (score 2):

The equality operator is supported in Django. To solve your code issue, I'd have used :

```
{% if firewalls %}
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>IP address</th>
    <th>Function</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
{% endif %}
<tbody>
{% for firewall in firewalls %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ host_ip }} : {{ firewall.from_port }}</td>

    {% if firewall.to_port==22 %} <td>Ssh Service</td>
    {% elif firewall.to_port==80 %} <td>Web Service</td>
    {% else %} <td>Unknown Service</td>{% endif %}

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% ifequal firewall.to_port 22 %} <td>Ssh Service</td>{% endifequal %}
    {% ifequal firewall.to_port 80 %} <td>Web Service</td>{% endifequal %}
    {% if firewall.to_port !=22 and if firewall.to_port !=80   %} <td>Unknown Service</td>{% endif %}
```

for every `ifequal` u need to close it with `endifequal` u missed one

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to judge the variable `to_port` is `22` or `80` or someone else.