# Django `ifnotequal` tag

Tags: python, django

I want to use the `ifnotequal` tag to judge whether a variable is equal to a certain value. This is the code:

```
{% ifequal firewall.to_port 22 %} <td>Ssh Service</td>{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal firewall.to_port 80 %} <td>Web Service</td>{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal firewall.to_port 25 %} <td>Mail Service</td>{% endifequal %}
{% ifnotequal firewall.to_port 80 or 22 or 25 %} <td>Unknown Service</td>{% endifnotequal %}
```

The code is wrong. I don't know how to use `or` in the `ifnotequal` tag. How do I write this? Thanks a lot.

Finally, I use:

```
{% ifequal firewall.to_port 22 %} <td>Ssh Service(Port 22)</td>{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal firewall.to_port 80 %} <td>Web Service(Port 80)</td>{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal firewall.to_port 25 %} <td>Mail Service(Port 25)</td>{% endifequal %}
{% if firewall.to_port != 25 and firewall.to_port != 22 and firewall.to_port != 80 %}
<td>Unknows Service</td>{% endif %}
```

It seems like stupid.

Comment: posted again ..does previous worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Invalid block tag: endelse and ifequal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483555/django-invalid-block-tag-endelse-and-ifequal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use the `if` template tag rather than `ifequal`. It can have multiple `elif` clauses, and one final `else` clause that will be used if none of the `elif` clauses were used. EG:

```
{% if firewall.to_port==22 %} <td>Ssh Service</td>
{% elif firewall.to_port==80 %} <td>Web Service</td>
{% elif firewall.to_port==25 %} <td>Mail Service</td>
{% else %} <td>Unknown Service</td>{% endif %}
```

Depending on how your `to_port` call works you might need to compare against strings instead of integers.

Upon checking the duplicate link Henrik Andersson posted in the comments above, I see someone already suggested this approach there. It's not the only option, but it'll work if you don't want to change the behavior of your view/model instances.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier and better for performance to do this in your views before you send your object to the template:

```
def some_view(request):
    port_names = {22: 'SSH Service', 80: 'Web Service', 25: 'SMTP Service'}

    firewall_objects = Firewall.objects.all()
    object_list = []

    for firewall in firewall_objects:
        object_list.append((firewall,
                            port_names.get(firewall.to_port, 'Unknown Service')))

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'object_list': object_list})
```

Now in your template, your life is easy:

```
<ul>
{% for obj, description in object_list %}
    <li>{{ obj.to_port }} - {{ description }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```